# FTP in a Metro App

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to create an FTP Application in Metro and C# but the FTP class in System.Net has been removed and now I can't figure out how to do this. I've looked into the BackgroundUploader but can't understand how I can bring back directory structures etc.

Does anyone have any experience doing this, I know it is achievable since there is an app already available on the Windows Store.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe those applications use third-party components, for example FTPSBlackbox package of our SecureBlackbox product, which supports WinRT. Note: Windows RT API has differences from common .NET Framework API so existing .NET components won't work with WinRT API - they need special tune-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked it yet, since I just started to look for it. In this article they're sharing an FTP sample in C#.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWindowsStoreAppFTPDownloa-88a90bd9

Regards,
Herb

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35902-create-an-ftp-class-library-in-c%23/. It's a C# implementation of a FTP client using sockets, unless you have advanced requirements this may be sufficient for you.

And if you need more you could Always expand on his example!

Comment: That code would need rework for Windows RT API, as sockets are very different between .NET Framework and .NET/WinRT API.

Comment: Sure, I'm not saying it will work as-is, but it is a socket implementation and the code is small enough that it should be possible to rework it to match WinRT API. I think the complex thing is to understand the sequence of calls etc. ti implement FTP protocol, not to port between differnt socket implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at this sample below. The difference from the Microsoft sample is the use of sockets:
- [Windows 8.1 Sockets: Ftp Client Sample in C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-8-SocketsFtp-4fc23b33)