# Windows 8 upload file via FTP

Tags: c#, windows-8, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FTP in a Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886362/ftp-in-a-metro-app)

Does anyone know how to upload files via FTP on Windows 8?
I tried to use the FtpWebRequest class but it is not available on Windows 8. The class BackgroundUploader also does not support the protocol FTP... any solution?

Comment: @DSilva - Since you didn't specify Windows Store Applications then FtpWebRequest certainly IS available on a Windows 8 Desktop application.  If your talking about a Windows Store Application then this thread and the link it goes to should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886362/ftp-in-a-metro-app